# I want to learn Visual C++ game development?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to start learning game programming on windows platform using Visual studio C++ can anybody guide me how to start how to develop a simple game what other libraries i need to add and other tools can any one guide me ??

hoping for quick and positive response

Comment: You can also query http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Tip: learn C++ programming before you start learning how to write games in C++. Consider C#/XNA as an alternative - it's a less steeper learning curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start here : http://nehe.gamedev.net/

It's about OpenGL. Then read other gamedev.net sections :D

Comment: nehe is the best starting place for a beginner:)

Comment: Actually I'm not convinced nehe is a good starting point. Problem with nehe is that most opengl tutorials are relatively old, meaning they are based on pre opengl 3.0 (meaning deprecated) functionality, which in my experience makes for a faster start, but much slower progression (in unlearning what one has learned so far and learning the more modern ways of doing thinks (vbos, shaders...). So I think it's a much better option to directly start with opengl 3.x tutorials (although still few and far between there are some out there).

Comment: Well, I am still believe good old OpenGL is what is needed. Dealing with complex stuff directly is.... to complex :-D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can investigate XNA from Microsoft[. This](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml) link may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at one of the well-known 2D graphics libraries, i.e. SFML, SDL.
Note that knowledge of the language is a requirement. I personally don't think that learning C++ while writing computer games is a good idea - first make sure you are fluent in C++.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ogre3d.org is one of the most popular OpenSource 3d Engine. 
It is written in C++ and requires you to know the language.
Take a look at the website. There are lots of info and samples.

Answer (score 0):

My first game I programmed was in C++.  To that point, I had only used C, Java, and Python.  Everyone else in the class was using C# / XNA.

I put a lot more effort into that class than was required.  Coding a game from scratch in C++ is a lot harder than starting with XNA.  I learned a lot, but the end result could have probably been accomplished using XNA in about half the time.  I did, however, become familiar with C++.

If you are looking to *learn*, start at the [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net) site, as mentioned by BarsMonster.  If you are looking to make a game, start with [XNA](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

A background in graphics programming is unavoidable. I would therefore start with reading a book about OpenGL. An excellent book would be "[OpenGL SuperBible Fifth Edition](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/)" -- newest edition (2010). It introduces state-of-the-art OpenGL programming with shaders (GLSL).

You can find example code -- sorted by chapters -- on the [Super Bible website](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/). The examples do not only include source code, but also Visual Studio projects and all the necessary libraries ([freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)). That should give you a good start.

You will need a decent graphics card to be able to run the book examples. Your card should support at least OpenGL version 3.0 -- preferably version 3.3. You can easily check the OpenGL version by downloading the  [Windows binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.5.7/glew-1.5.7-win32.zip/download) of the [GLEW library](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and running the glewinfo executable in the bin sub-folder. This will create a file glewinfo.txt. Open the file and search for "OpenGL version".